# using the product rule for $k\cdot\sec\left(kx\right)\tan\left(kx\right)$

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives

So as stated above I have the function: y'= $k\cdot \sec\left(kx\right)\tan\left(kx\right)$

Which I got from $y = sec(kx)$

And I am supposed to find $y''= k^2y(2y^2-1)$

And taking the derivative of this I would obviously need to use the product rule and I would get:

$k^2*sec(kx)*tan(kx)*tan(kx) + k^2*sec(kx)*sec^2(kx)$

by using the already defined derivative of sec(kx) and tan(kx) I got the above.

However, it is supposed to be: 
$k^2*sec^2(kx)*tan^2(x) + k^2*sec^3(kx)$

I don't know if i'm omitting some trigonometric identity, but i'm utterly clueless to where they got the extra $sec(kx)$ from?'

Distributing my answer I get:

$k^2*sec(kx)*tan^2(kx) + k^2*sec^3(kx)$

(in case I was unclear)opposed to their answer:

$k^2*sec^2(kx)*tan^2(kx) + k^2*sec^3(kx)$

So what's happening here?

Thank you i advance!

*EDIT: regarding the constant term "k", I forgot to include it for the first edit.It is now all revised!

Comment: Your derivative is right, there is only one power of secx in that first term. May I ask why you're getting k^2 though?

Comment: Yes I know. Hence:

$k^2sec(x)tan(x)*tan(x)+....$

Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: There is either an error in your original formula or an error in your answer because you shouldn't get a $k^2$ from a $k$

Comment: I apologize. I forgot to include a  "k" inside the parentheses

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is right, apart from the constant term. We are trying to solve  $\frac{d}{dx}k\sec(x)\tan(x)$, and by the constant multiple rule we can pull out the constant and just deal with $k(\frac{d}{dx}\sec(x)\tan(x))$, which you correctly found to be $\sec(x)\tan^2(x)+\sec^3(x)$. Multiplying this by the constant term we pulled out, making the final derivative $k\sec(x)\tan^2(x)+k\sec^3(x)$.

Comment: With your edit my answer is obsolete, the answer you obtained was 100% correct, theirs is flawed.

Comment: I've made a new edit(sorry for making it hard for you). Something I initially thought might've been irrelevent to my problem.

orignial function: $y= sec(kx)$

The first derivative of the function:  $y'= k*sec(x)(tan(x))$

And I am supposed to find  $y′′=k^2y(2y^2−1)$